# bootsy editor not working for nested attribtues added through nested_form gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nested-forms

I am using [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) for managing associated entities in the form.
I am using [bootsy](https://github.com/volmer/bootsy) for displaying a wysiwyg editor. And the nested attributes do not have a wysiwyg field, although it works for the entity of an un-nested entity on page, but do not for a nested entity.

```
<%= nested_form_for @project do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.bootsy_area :project_description %> ''WORKS''
  <%= f.fields_for :tasks do |task_form| %>
    <%= task_form.text_field :task_name %>
    <%= task_form.bootsy_area :task_description %> ''Do NOT WORKS''
    <%= task_form.link_to_remove "Remove this task" %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a task", :tasks %></p>
<% end %>
```

The project dscription renders as a wysiwyg field, but the nested field, task_details render as a normal text area.
If someone can share her/his thoughts, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described at the docs of **nested_form**, you should activate it on newly-created elements manually using js events. Following example if you're using jQuery.

```
$(document).on('nested:fieldAdded', function(event){
  Bootsy.init();
});
```

this works for me (also using **nested_form**).